# Pandas calculation on subcategories

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
Name    Department  Spent
Jack    Cars    150
Jack    Clothes 50
Jack    Food    200
Jill    Cars    50
Jill    Clothes 500
Jill    Food    200
```

and I want to calculate the % spent as :

```
% Spent = Amount Spent per User/ Total Amount Spent by User
```

the end result should like this:

```
Name    Department  Spent   % Spent
Jack    Cars    150 38%
Jack    Clothes 50  13%
Jack    Food    200 50%
Jill    Cars    50  7%
Jill    Clothes 500 67%
Jill    Food    200 27%
```

Is there a simple way of doing this. I can do it through loop but that is very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group` the dataframe on `Name` and transform `Spent` using `sum`, then divide `Spent` by transformed `sum` followed by `mul` and `round` to get the percent:

```
df['% Spent'] = df['Spent'].div(df.groupby('Name')['Spent']\
                           .transform('sum')).mul(100).round(0)
```

Or if you want the values in column `% Spent` as strings, you can directly use `%` format speciefier in `map` call:

```
df['% Spent'] = df['Spent'].div(df.groupby('Name')['Spent']\
                           .transform('sum')).map('{:.0%}'.format)
```

---

```
   Name Department  Spent % Spent
0  Jack       Cars    150     38%
1  Jack    Clothes     50     12%
2  Jack       Food    200     50%
3  Jill       Cars     50      7%
4  Jill    Clothes    500     67%
5  Jill       Food    200     27%
```